# python how to convert from string.template object to string

Tags: python, string, templates

This is very simple.I am sure I am missing something silly.

```
fp = open(r'D:\UserManagement\invitationTemplate.html', 'rb')        
html = Template(fp.read())
fp.close()
html.safe_substitute(toFirstName='jibin',fromFirstName='Vishnu')
print html
```

When i run this code in intepreter directly,I get the proper output.
But when I run it from a file.I get `<string.Template object at 0x012D33B0>`.How do I convert from string.Template object to string.I have tried `str(html)`.By the bye wasn't print statement supposed to do that(string conversion) ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`safe_substitute` **returns**, as a string, the template with the substitutions made. This way, you can reuse the same template for multiple substitutions. So your code has to be

```
print html.safe_substitute(toFirstName='jibin',fromFirstName='Vishnu')
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) you should take the return Value of safe_substitute

```
fp = open(r'D:\UserManagement\invitationTemplate.html', 'rb')        
html = Template(fp.read())
fp.close()
result = html.safe_substitute(toFirstName='jibin',fromFirstName='Vishnu')
print result
```

Answer (score 2):

the result is returned by safe_substitute method:

```
result = html.safe_substitute(toFirstName='jibin',fromFirstName='Vishnu')
print result
```